# How to connect to mongodb with authorization in meanjs?

Tags: mongodb, meanjs

I'm new to meanjs.
My problem is: my local mongodb has username/password, and I can't run meanjs demo successfully.

I git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/meanjs.git 
And try to run it(npm run on Windows 10), but got this error:

> Could not connect to MongoDB!
>   { MongoError: Authentication failed.
>      at Function.MongoError.create (D:\Cordova\AzureMeanDemo\meanjs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)

then I set username/password in `meanjs\config\env\development.js` like:

```
db: {
    uri: process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://' + (process.env.DB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR || 'localhost') + '/mean-dev',
    options: {
      user: 'superAdmin', //here
      pass: '*****'  //here
    },
    // Enable mongoose debug mode
    debug: process.env.MONGODB_DEBUG || false
  },
...
```

but I still got the same error.

I've searched on google for a whole day, but got nothing about this.

Could anyone help me on this problem?

-------------- Solved -------------------

I changed uri: 'mongodb://username:passwd@localhost/mean-dev?authSource=adm‌​in'. It worked for me.

Comment: For localhost just use `uri: 'mongodb://localhost/mean-dev'` no need options...

Comment: My MongoDB shell version v3.6.1

Comment: @ShaishabRoy but I run mongod as a serverice with -auth, and has username and password.

Comment: then can try this `uri: 'mongodb://userName:Password@localhost/mean-dev' `and before that ensure you have set *userName and password* for **database** not **account** userName and password and is your service running locally ?

Comment: @ShaishabRoy yes my mongod service is running locally. And i found i missed another warning: Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials. --- is this cause the problem?

Comment: This is the warning not error for the version 3.6 not for less than < 3.6

Comment: @ShaishabRoy Yes, that warning do not cause the problem. I tried to rewrite uri in development.js to : mongodb://userName:Password@localhost/mean-dev, the problem still occurs.

Comment: @ShaishabRoy I found uri: 'mongodb://username:passwd@localhost/mean-dev?authSource=admin' worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/projectName,{user:'',pass:''});
```